# Hibernate Class level validation

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

Well, I read several issues (here and other sites) about class level validation with hibernate, I created the annotation and validation class, but when validation returns false, I get an exception (when validation returns true its ok) that the class is not valid (obviously because validation returned false), my doubt is: it was not to return a validation message as well? why is returning an exception, the code:

ValidBlock.java

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidBlockValidator.class)
public @interface ValidBlock {
    String message() default "{app.ValidBlock.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

ValidBlockValidator.java

```
public class ValidBlockValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidBlock, Block> {

   @Override
   public void initialize(ValidBlock aBlock) {}

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(Block value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

I made the test and i'm pretty sure i recieved the Block object, as when validation return true is fine i just return false to test.

Block.java

```
@ValidBlock
public class Block{
   ...
}
```

and the error:

> Grave: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation
>   failed for classes [com.labsys.model.Block] during persist time for
>   groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{app.ValidBlock.message}',
>   propertyPath=, rootBeanClass=class com.labsys.model.Block,
>   messageTemplate='{app.ValidBlock.message}'} ]     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:185)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:981)
>
> Grave: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException obtido
>   durante o processamento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5:
>   UIComponent-ClientId=blockForm:j_idt14,
>   Message=javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation
>   failed for classes [com.labsys.model.Block] during persist time for
>   groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{app.ValidBlock.message}',
>   propertyPath=, rootBeanClass=class com.labsys.model.Block,
>   messageTemplate='{app.ValidBlock.message}'} ] Grave:
>   javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for
>   classes [com.labsys.model.Block] during persist time for groups
>   [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[
>     ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{app.ValidBlock.message}',
>   propertyPath=, rootBeanClass=class com.labsys.model.Block,
>   messageTemplate='{app.ValidBlock.message}'} ]

Comment: i was trying to make just a custom validation, not creating my own framework. and it's kinda possible, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e341

Comment: @Shahzeb - that is how you create a custom validator with JSR303.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `ValidationMessages.properties` file and make it available at the root of your classpath, in order for the validation framework to extrapolate your custom message.

Comment: even if i set the message like this:
@ValidBlock(message="That's a error") ?

Comment: Hibernate Validator always gives you nasty exceptions with a useless message when it finds the error during flush time.  If you want user friendliness you need to run the validator yourself ahead of time.  If you find a way around this I am eager to hear about it :)

Comment: @Affe Take a look at javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException class. As you can see, the Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations property is the same thing returned when you manually calls the validator.validate(obj). So, it is expected that you catch this exception and use these constraintViolations as you wish.